# Bluetooth en Android: StartDiscovery no funciona, no se puede encontrar dispositivos

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se pueda conectar a dispositivos bluetooth.

El código lo realicé siguiendo las indicaciones de `developer.android` para poder detectar dispositivos bluetooth no sincronizados. Utilice println() para observar si se logra obtener el nombre y mac de los dispositivos disponibles obtenidos del BroadcastReceiver, pero no me llega a imprimir nada por consola.

Agregue los permisos en el manifest:

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH

android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar el problema?

Este es mi código:

```
class ConfiguracionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityConfiguracionBinding
private lateinit var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityConfiguracionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val btManager = this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    btAdapter = btManager.adapter

    if(btAdapter.isEnabled){
       Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth activado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       discoverBluetooth()
    }else{
       Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth desactivado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
           
}

fun discoverBluetooth() {

    val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
    filter.addAction(ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    if(btAdapter.isDiscovering){
        println("isDiscovering")
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
    }
    btAdapter.startDiscovery()
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when(intent.action) {

            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                println("EStoy dentro de la funcion")
                val device: BluetoothDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                val deviceName = device?.name
                val deviceHardwareAddress = device?.address // MAC address
                println("Name: $deviceName, MAC: $deviceHardwareAddress")
            }

            ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED ->{
                println("Error")
                context.unregisterReceiver(this)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
    unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}
}
```

Esto es lo que me sale
[image: Mensaje del run]

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Por favor agrega la salida esperada o el mensaje de error que estas teniendo. Saludos

Comment: `Me sale que mi dispositivo tiene conectado el bluetooth, pero luego de eso no sucede nada más.` Por favor indica qué es lo que esperas que suceda luego de conectar el bluetooth

Comment: Gracias por las indicaciones, ya realice los cambios.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo último, agrega los errores como texto y no como imágen. Saludos!

Comment: En realidad no me devuelve nada, ese es el problema que tengo, ya que parece como si no funcionara el BroadcastReceiver y por lo cual no se inicia la deteccion de dispositivos.